# limit number of characters displayed in live preview of input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

As I type text in the input field, the value is displayed live in `p` element: http://jsfiddle.net/HC9KD/

How can I display only as many as 25 first characters in the preview?
I tried using some methods found on this site, but they did not seem to work for me.

`text-overflow: ellipsis` - will not do.

Appreciate any ideas.

HTML

```
<p id="preview"></p>
<input type="text" id="typedtext">
```

JavaScript

```
var wpcomment = document.getElementById('typedtext');

wpcomment.onkeyup = wpcomment.onkeypress = function(){
    document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/HC9KD/1/

Use `slice()` as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

```
var wpcomment = document.getElementById('typedtext');

wpcomment.onkeyup = wpcomment.onkeypress = function(){
    document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML = this.value.slice(0,25);
}
```

Update:

I took the idea from ragatskynet and added the dots at the end if the number of characters of the input is longer than 25 characters. See the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/HC9KD/7/

```
var wpcomment = document.getElementById('typedtext');

wpcomment.onkeyup = wpcomment.onkeypress = function(){
    document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML = this.value.slice(0,25) + function(x) {
        if(x.length > 25) { return " ..."} else {return ""};
    }(this.value);
}
```

Comment: Your first example works good for me. I appreciate all the answers here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substr()`.

```
var wpcomment = document.getElementById('typedtext');

wpcomment.onkeyup = wpcomment.onkeypress = function(){
    if(this.value.length <= 25){
        document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML = this.value;    
    } else {
        document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML = this.value.substr(0,25) + "...";
    }
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HC9KD/4/

Comment: In my opinion, the if-clause is redundant here. `substr` still works on strings with a fewer number of characters than the number used as the cut-off limit.

Comment: Sure (my original code was written the way you thought), but you should not need to add the dots if you are under 25 chars.

Comment: I implemented them in my solution as an anonymous function for to avoid assigning `this.value` twice.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/HC9KD/3/

```
var wpcomment = document.getElementById('typedtext');

wpcomment.onkeyup = wpcomment.onkeypress = function(){
    if (document.getElementById('preview').innerText.length < 25) {
        document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML = this.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would not preview anything if the length of the text is 25 characters or more, would it?!

Comment: Okay, sorry. You got a point there. Nevertheless, once the character limit has been reached, in my example nothing updates anymore in the section of zero to twenty-five characters. Did you notice that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var wpcomment = document.getElementById('typedtext');
var count=1;
wpcomment.onkeyup = wpcomment.onkeypress = function(){
    if(count<=50){
         document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML = this.value;

     }
     count++;
 }
```